# Slack Incoming Webhook API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slack-api

I'm able to POST to the Slack incoming API endpoint via CURL, but when trying with the below its not working. I'm assuming the formatting if off. How can I fix this?

```
parms = {text: text_for_slack, channel: "#customer_sessions", username: "SessionBot", icon_emoji: ":raised_hands:"}
x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(ENV['SessionSlackURL'].to_s), parms.to_s)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can post using two methods (text from slack configuration for incoming webhook) :

> You have two options for sending data to the Webhook URL above:
>   Send a JSON string as the payload parameter in a POST request
>   Send a JSON string as the body of a POST request

**json in the body.**

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require "json"

parms = {
    text: text_for_slack, 
    channel: "#customer_sessions", 
    username: "SessionBot", 
    icon_emoji: ":raised_hands:"
}

uri = URI.parse(ENV['SessionSlackURL'])
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.body = parms.to_json

response = http.request(request)
```

**json as parameter**

```
parms_form = { 
    "payload" => {
        text: text_for_slack, 
        channel: "#customer_sessions", 
        username: "SessionBot", 
        icon_emoji:":raised_hands:"
        }.to_json
    }

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data(parms_form)
```

Comment: The subtle point here that I kept missing was that it's the _inner_ dictionary that needs to be converted using `.to_json`, not the whole parms_form.  Thanks!